# Could not create secure SSL/TLS Channel to the API after shifting server

Tags: ssl, iis

My application installed in IIS 7 was using SSL connection to a bank API. Recently I had shifted my web application to IIS 8 on different server. After that we couldnt create secure SSL/TLS connection to the bank API. I had imported the certificate shared by bank to Console Root\Certificates(Local Computer)\Personal\Certificates). I had imported certificate for intermediate certification authorities. In webconfig, the path to the certificate is specified as my old server was using.

Bank API is not using any certificate from our end for authentication.But still I am getting SSL/TLS error. Am I missing anything? Appreciate if anybody could help me to  solve the issue

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze TLS handshakes. That should tell what might be wrong.